# How to re-load values in object using vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, state, vuex

Following is my goal list component:

```
export default {
  name: 'GoalsList',
  components: {
    TestComponent,
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters('goalList', ['goalList']),
  },
};
```

This goal list contains array of objects. From this page goals details page gets opened and goal can be updated from this page in modal box. Values stores in states. However, updated value doesn't get reflected in this goal List.

How can I update this goal list with updated values?

Comment: please share your store code

Comment: Try to read this: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html Mutations helps you to change state values.

Comment: it would be a bit clear if you shared your source code. I mean only the part which is not working and your vuex.

Answer (score 0):

You should use deep watcher on your state:

```
data: () => {
    return {
      goals: []
    };
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState('goalList', ['goalList']),
  },
  watch: {
    goalList: {
      handler(updatedGoals) {
        this.goals = updatedGoals
      },
      deep: true
    }
  }
```

Comment: defining `goals: []` and watching `goalList ` is unnecessary, you will always have updated value in `...mapGetters('goalList', ['goalList'])`

Comment: The thing is that your getter will not work, because it's not pure. Better to use mapState + deep watcher. https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/issues/145#issuecomment-230488443